# Apache POI A3 Page shows two pages in print preview

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
   sheet = workbook.createSheet(studentMarkSheetVO.getBranchName()+"_"+studentMarkSheetVO.g    etAcademicYear().split("-")[0]+"_Batch");
   sheet.getPrintSetup().setVResolution((short)300);
   sheet.getPrintSetup().setPaperSize(HSSFPrintSetup.A3_PAPERSIZE);
   sheet.getPrintSetup().setLandscape(true);
   sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitHeight((short)2000);
```

my page preview shows splitting of a page , in two separate pages.
one has only one record and other page shown as blank with footer.
I also tried :

```
sheet.setFitToPage(true);
PrintSetup printsetup= sheet.getPrintSetup();
printsetup.setFitHeight((short)0);
printsetup.setFitWidth((short)1);
```

But problem persists. any solutions....please provide your valuable suggestions.
Thank you all.

Comment: You probably need to compare the XML files inside the .xlsx file (a .xlsx is actually a zip-file) and compare it with o file that you create in Excel manually, then you might be able to identify where the difference is, then it is either something you can set or something that needs to be reported to Apache POI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes answer is here i found it after spending few hours , on internet.
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FitTo